# Suppress lint warning for identical icon in different configurable resource folders

Tags: android, lint

I get the following warning when I try to add the same image for two traditional Chinese locales. The problem is I need to specify this as the default would be the English icon but the same icon is needed for both locales. Please let me know if there is anyway to get around this warning or suppress it.

"IconDuplicatesConfig
The `icon.webp` icon has identical contents in the following configuration folders: drawable-zh-rHK-mdpi, drawable-zh-rTW-mdpi

If an icon is provided under different configuration parameters such as `drawable-hdpi` or `-v11`, they should typically be different. This detector catches cases where the same icon is provided in different configuration folder which is usually not intentional."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could untick the option as the fig:
[image]